# Uninstall nspr in linux

Tags: software-installation

I installed `nspr` by first downloading its `tar.gz` file, unzipped the file and finally by writing

`sudo ./configure`

I want to un-install it now. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you run `./configure` with `sudo` - that is normally not right.

#### You did not install it

If you did not run something like

```
make install
sudo make install
```

you did not install it in the first place.
Just remove the directory.

If you had run

```
make install
```

that would have created lots of files, but all inside the current and the subdirectories, not outside.

#### If you had installed it

Running

```
sudo make install
```

would have moved just the right files to the right places outside, like `/usr/bin`, `/usr/share/man/man1/`, or `/usr/local/bin`.

Often you can undo it with `sudo make uninstall`.

Otherwise, you can run `sudo make install` again, overwriting the same files, and keep the log output.
From that, you can see which files were created - to remove them manually, or to just accept and ignore them.

If you really think that `./configure` created files outside, you can use the same method:

Just rename the directory, unpack the .tar.gz again to the same place, and run ./configure again to see what it creates - it will not create more than you already have.

Comment: perhaps you are correct. i ran ./configure so it runs like script. It automatically creates new files or something... not in one place, but in many places. So if i have to delete the folder created by ./configure i will have to first find out where all the files are which it created and then manually del those files. So i was asking is their a better way to do it

Next i am new to linux, so not much aware of the rights and wrong ( regarding ./configure with sudo )...but i will keep this in mind, would follow what you said from now on.

Comment: It't the right way to run `./configure`, just withour `sudo`. I think it creates only files (mostly `Makefile`) in the current directory, and in subdirs, but not outside. Normally, you run `make` then (creates many files, but not outside) and finally `sudo make install`, which moves just the right files outside.

Comment: You can just unpack the tar.gz again, and run `./configure` again to see what it creates - it will not create more than you already have.